# Adding Subview To UIViewController Makes UITablview Subview Disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This code is called inside of a function that is called programatically. The UITableView that it is inserted over has been put in the `UIViewController` in a storyboard. The `UIViewController` is embedded in a navigationController.

```
let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width / 2
    containerView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.width / 2
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = containerView.bounds
    containerView.center = self.view.center
    containerView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    self.view.insertSubview(containerView, aboveSubview: matchTableView)
    indicator?.startAnimation()
```

I'm just trying to add an activity indicator over the tableview. The actual activity indicator shows up just fine but I need to put a background behind it so it can be seen correctly. As soon as any type of subview is added to the `UIViewController` the table disappears.

Comment: Are you trying to have this containerView  as the background for your  activity indicator?

Comment: Correct, that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: In that case, you come up with all that functionality in one single view, say ProgressView, and let it take care of all needed functionality for your activity progress display. In your current implementation it sounds like you tend to  create multiple views in different places and trying to order them together, etc

Comment: I think you should be adding the blur view to the tableView (ie. `matchTableView.addSubview(blurEffectView)`. Meaning you don't need containerView.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, you're right, that would be better. That'll be the way I go. However, having just tried it, it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I had been adding the subview in a function long after the view rendered itself. The way to get this done was to add the view in `viewDidAppear`. After that I could manipulate it any way I needed. Any period after `viewDidAppear` in the life cycle and the tableView disappears. I don't know why or if this is the correct way to avoid that issue but this works as a solution.

Adding it in `viewDidLoad` does not add it to the render tree. It will be there but it will have been too early for it to display properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
let containerView = UIView()
...
containerView.opaque = false
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: I need the containerView to have a background color. And even still, that doesn't work. The tableView completely disappears as soon as a subview is added to itself or to the viewController.

Answer (score 0):

The tableView is disappearing because you are inserting the container view 
above it .

You nedd to add your activity indictor above the table view , where the activity indicator view frame is less than the table view frame

```
matchTableView.addSubView(containerView)
```

Comment: The tableView disappears whenever a view is added to either itself or the viewController.